# How to implement client side password protection for web content?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to password protect a section of a page using JavaScript.
The user would see a simple input field and submit button, upon entering the correct password, the user would gain access to the "hidden" content.

Currently, there is no way to view the "hidden" content since it gets hidden every time there is a page reload (which happens when the form submits).

Yes, I know this is not considered "password protection" since the password is found in the js itself, but this doesn't matter for this particular scenario.

Here is the code I have, thanks for any help.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload=function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("hiddenContent");
    e.style.display = 'none';   
};
function showPass(form){
    var pass = form.pwd.value;

    if(pass == "password") {
        e.style.display = 'block';      
    }
}
</script>

<form action="#" onsubmit="showPass(form);return false">
Please Enter The Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
<div id="hiddenContent">Here is the Hidden content...</div>
```

How can I have the hidden content view-able after correct password submission?

Comment: So, what's the question then?

Comment: How Can I have the "hidden content" view-able upon correct password submission?

Comment: don't use javascript! every person with chrome inspector or firebug or IE inspector can change the css and show the hidden part. Use server-side languages!

Comment: Add a success function to your ajax call and show the div there, but yeah, you'll want to do checking server side.

Comment: When you submit the hidden form, send the password back to the server and then have the reload return the password to the javascript. If it's a valid password and is there on page load, don't hide that part.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot access the server...I am working on a (limited) platform, that only allows basic html/css/js changes any tips?

Comment: Then store something in a cookie that says the password was entered. But you have to decide how to remove or ignore the cookie after a while. Perhaps set it to expire at midnight.

Comment: you could use a password to encrypt some text, and then make the user have to enter the same password (decryption key) to decrypt it via javascript in the browser: http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/ that would be fairly hard for a web user to bypass

Comment: @MatthewLock very cool concept! I have a working version with Jeffman's solution below but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide credentials in client-side javascript application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873113/how-to-hide-credentials-in-client-side-javascript-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that crash your code and halt execution. This causes your form to submit, which you don't want, and none of your other code runs either.

**onsubmit="showPass(form)** should be **onsubmit="showPass(this)**

**e** is NOT a global variable. It is enclosed by the anonymous function and not visible outside. This means that showPass() doesn't know what **e** refers to. Change this

**var e = document.getElementById("hiddenContent");**

to

**e = document.getElementById("hiddenContent");** (no var keyword)

or (maybe better) get a unique reference to that element in showPass()

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to do exactly the same.

And I found a post that explains that with hash

[How to hide credentials in client-side javascript application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64873164/13795525)

first you need to use the hash function to encrypt your password, in my case the password is "SecretLog1"

```js
hashCode = s =>
  s.split("").reduce((a, b) => {
    a = (a << 5) - a + b.charCodeAt(0);
    return a & a;
  }, 0);
const password = "SecretLog1";
alert(hashCode(password));
```

```html
<h1>HASH YOUR PASSWORD</h1>
<p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Then you have to get the value returned form the hash, in the case of password "SecretLog1" is "541756509" and paste it in the hash decoding function and then you can create a nice page

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('secretCheckbox').style.display = 'none';

};


function unlock(){
  document.getElementById('factoryAlert').style.display = '';
}

function hideUnlock(){
  document.getElementById('factoryAlert').style.display = 'none';
}


function checkFactoryPwd() {
  var pass = document.getElementById('factoryPwd').value;
  const hashCode = s =>
    s.split('').reduce((a, b) => {
      a = (a << 5) - a + b.charCodeAt(0);
      return a & a;
    }, 0);
  if (hashCode(pass) == '541756509') {
    alert('Welcome!');
    document.getElementById('secretCheckbox').style.display = '';
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, wrong password!');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!--    Bootstrap --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class='alert alert-info' role='alert' id='factoryAlert' style="text-align: center;">
              Now you showed this alert, press X to hide it or fill it with right password
              <br>
              <form onsubmit="return checkFactoryPwd()" action='/' method='post' >
              <input type='password' name='factoryPwd' id='factoryPwd'>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick='checkFactoryPwd()'>OK</button>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm ' onclick='hideUnlock()'>&nbsp;X&nbsp;</button>
            </div>
            
<div class="form-check" id="secretCheckbox">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
    Secret checkbox
  </label>
  <div style='text-align: center;'><input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='submitCur' type='submit' value='Submit'></div>
 </form>            
</div>
```