# How to hide credentials in client-side javascript application

Tags: javascript

I have a simple `javascript` **client-side** application. And there are two variables namely `username` and `password` that has values as below:

```
var username = "test123";
var password = "test@123"
```

But the problem is, since is this a client side `javascript` application, these two values should be hardcoded in order to use, but **I don't want to expose them either**

What would be the best possible way to do this?

Eventhough I write these values to another javascript file and try to read it, when the page loads, the users can always see that file as well.

Is there a workaround for this kind of scenario?

Comment: TL;DR. Not possible. But... Read my answer...

Comment: Oh, so there is no possible way...

Comment: Not exactly. I clarified now... Where there's a will, there's a way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, you can't. But there's a work-around. You can hash the passwords in one way and send the hashes with salt over. You can't get the hashes dehashed. Let's say, we have a hashing function like this:

```
hashCode = s =>
  s.split("").reduce((a, b) => {
    a = (a << 5) - a + b.charCodeAt(0);
    return a & a;
  }, 0);
```

Now, with the above, we can do something like this:

```js
hashCode = s =>
  s.split("").reduce((a, b) => {
    a = (a << 5) - a + b.charCodeAt(0);
    return a & a;
  }, 0);

const password = "Hello@123";
console.log(hashCode(password) == "-1094953564");
```

Have the password sent to the client as `-1094953564`, which stands for `Hello@123`. You can do a verification like the above. You don't need to send `Hello@123` in a plain text in the client.

**Final Solution**

Here's a simple snippet:

```js
function check() {
  var pass = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
  const hashCode = s =>
    s.split("").reduce((a, b) => {
      a = (a << 5) - a + b.charCodeAt(0);
      return a & a;
    }, 0);
  if (hashCode(pass) == "-1094953564") {
    console.log("Welcome!");
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry, wrong password!");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return check()">
  <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Password..." />
  <input type="submit" value="Check Password" />
</form>
```

Formatted the above code to show that there's no instance of `Hello@123`.

Comment: I don't understand this. so you have put `const password`, so when the page loads, doesn't the user able to see that as well?

Comment: @JananathJayarathna I have added a snippet to explain how you can use this.

Comment: @JananathJayarathna Try `Hello@123` and also another password and press enter to check it out! 

Comment: And I said said, I have only a client-sided application, and no server. it is just an `html` file with some javascript codes

Comment: @JananathJayarathna I didn't mention a thing about server. It was the other answer. Where did I say anything about server?

Comment: And As I said, those values are hardcoded, i am not getting those values using a form

Answer (score 0):

You could have the credentials stored on a back-end app. Use these credentials in the back-end and send a request to the original authentication server that needs the credentials.

```
Your Client =====>  Your server =======> Resource Server
```

Additionally, you could make your server require a token(from your client) before sending requests to the resource server.

Comment: Apparently, the author didn't mention anything like he doesn't have access to a server.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the credentials in the source code is **not recommended** which make your application *vulnerable and fragile*.

**Possible options:**

- Try using a `REST API` approach to meet your purpose (if you can)
- Try `Variable Masking` techniques using https://jscrambler.com/ or equivalent tools